# Неправильно десериализуется integer в Json.Net

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, json.net

У меня есть простое тело запроса, состоящее из следующего json:

```
{
   "code": 11,
   "name": "abc"
}
```

Во время отладки при обработке POST-запроса в качестве аргумента поступает правильная строка, однако после использования `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacultyJson>(body.ToString())` поле `code` класса `FacultyJson` становится равным 0, при этом при десериализации без указания типа поле `code` становится равным вообще `null`.
Код метода:

```
public IActionResult AddFaculty(JsonElement body)
{
   var debug = body.ToString();
   FacultyJson faculty = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacultyJson>(body.ToString());

   DatabaseWorker.AddFaculty(faculty.Name, faculty.Code);
   return Ok();
}
```

Вот так выглядит `FacultyJson` (сам он вложен в другой класс):

```
private class FacultyJson
{
   [JsonProperty]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty]
   public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно, перепробовал все что мог, и публичные сеттеры (хотя изначально просто поля были), и атрибуты `JsonProperty`. Кто-нибудь знает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В `debug` что находится?

Comment: А Name-то у вас нормально задается? Вся эта штука - регистрозависимая, указывайте [JsonProperty("name_in_json")] над свойствами в классах и тогда не будет проблем

Comment: @Aarnihauta Json.NET по умолчанию не зависит от регистра. А вот System.Text.Json да, помню бывало у него такое, правда вроде изменили в последних версиях, нет?

Comment: @Aarnihauta А не, не изменили, стандартный System.Text.Json до сих пор [не любит](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8hRhC3) регистр из коробки. Но, вопросу это точно не поможет, ибо тут Json.Net. Тут больше напрягает то, что JSON вручную десериализируется, когда это должен делать сам asp.net, принимая его из запроса и возвращая полноценный объект, вот это да, странно, но регистр нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "{\"code\": 11,\"name\": \"abc\"}, то есть он корректный

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Проблема в том, что angular отправляет на сервер по сути анонимный тип, который еще и поименно не десериализуется, хотя имена совпадают

Comment: `public IActionResult AddFaculty(FacultyJson faculty)` - сделайте параметр нужного типа.

Comment: Послушайте, но ведь `JsonElement` - это структура из `System.Text.Json`. На кой вы смешали два разных АПИ для работы с json?

Comment: `AddFaculty(JsonElement` - это метод контроллера? Что-то не верится, что это будет работать. Как в него данные попадают?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Json.Net просто поддерживает динамическую типизацию. И да, этот контроллер работает, так как данные он выводит корректные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге исправилось изменением названий полей в `FacultyJson` и соответствующем анонимном типе внутри angular с `name` и `code` на `facultyName` и `facultyCode`:

```
private class FacultyJson
{
   [JsonProperty]
   public string FacultyName { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty]
   public int FacultyCode { get; set; }
}
```